# Jquery to change links to _blank if they don't start with a specific url/domain

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I know that `$("a[href='http://testtesttest.org/']").attr("target", "_blank");` will find and change all links that match the test url, but I'd like to know how to only change the links that do NOT match that URL. Essentially links that would take users to other webites -- outside links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$("a:not([href='http://testtesttest.org/'])")
```

If you want to select all those that don't **start** with this URL, you have to use the [*attribute starts with selector `^=`*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("a:not([href^='http://testtesttest.org/'])")
```

You mention:

> Essentially links that would take users to other webites -- outside links

That depends on how consistent the structure of internal URLs is. E.g. the previous shown selector would also select links such as

```
<a href="/images">Images</a>
```

or

```
<a href="foo/bar">Bar</a>
```

which are clearly internal. If **every** internal link starts with your domain name, than it is fine. If not, you either have the possibility to adjust those links, to have a consistent structure, or to use another selector:

```
$("a[href^='http']:not([href^='http://testtesttest.org/'])")
```

This will make sure that links with absolute and relative URLs are not selected.

If you also have links with other protocols, such as `file:`, it becomes even more involved.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much. I didn't even think of the relative URL's, I'm very grateful you pointed that out. Have an awesome day Felix!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on jQuery selectors:

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a:not([href^='http://testtesttest.org/'])")
    .attr("target", "_blank");
```

This will give you all URLs that don't start with your domain.